# Secure subdomain in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, nginx

We have a SSL certificate for secure.domain.com

Our Rails 3 app is hosted in Nginx and is available at www.domain.com

We need to secure *some* of the pages: Login (Devise) and a couple more.

Adding

```
:constraints => { :protocol => "https" }
```

to the routes, will make sure the page is served via SSL but doesn't change the subdomain from www to secure.

Any suggestions on how to work around this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should watch this Railscasts episode, it describes workaround with subdomains, also I think you can implement SSL support there: [Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?autoplay=true)

Hope it will help you.